# Вычисление степени

Tags: математика, javascript

На JS нужно считать похожие примеры

```
Math.pow( -2.17, 0.47 )
```

На что результат NaN

Google считает, результат -1.439....

Как провернуть это на JS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение есть

Гугл считал не правильно. Из-за меня, нужно было его спрашивать не

```
 -2.17 ^ 0.47
```

а

```
 (-2.17) ^ 0.47
```

Результат мним, JS на такое не способен